# Cannot use @Stateless annotation with maven

Tags: java, maven, ejb, java-ee-7

for some reason I cannot use the `@Stateless` or `@EJB` annotations in my project. I am using Maven and added several different dependencies trying to solve the issue, the last one I tried:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>povided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However I am not able to use the said annotations in my classes

[image: Intellij Idea Screenshot]

I also added the javaee-api-8.0.jar manually to the build path of the project and set its scope to provided, but that leads to an error during `maven clean install`: `import javax.ejb cannot be resolved`

So that approach didn't work out either. Additionally I checked if there is a correct SDK configured in the project and I can confirm that this looks correct.

I am using Intellij Idea Community Version. If anyone can point out an error I made or has a solution for this I would be very thankful.

Comment: Sometimes IntelliJ needs to refresh its Maven cache, or your Maven repository is outdated so you should run `mvn clean install -U` to force it to update.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately did not help. I still can't use anything from javax.ejb.

Comment: Check the spelling of your scope.

Comment: build it from the command line (mvn clean install) to check, then reimport your project.

Comment: What is the `povided` scope? Did you mean `provided`? If yes, is it a typo in your project or this question?

Comment: It was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. That and building it com CLI with reimporting the project worked. Thank you for helping me out!